# re.sub replace with matched content

Tags: python, regex, python-re, python-regex

Trying to get to grips with regular expressions in Python, I'm trying to output some HTML highlighted in part of a URL. My input is

```
images/:id/size
```

my output should be

```
images/<span>:id</span>/size
```

If I do this in Javascript

```
method = 'images/:id/size';
method = method.replace(/\:([a-z]+)/, '<span>$1</span>')
alert(method)
```

I get the desired result, but if I do this in Python

```
>>> method = 'images/:id/huge'
>>> re.sub('\:([a-z]+)', '<span>$1</span>', method)
'images/<span>$1</span>/huge'
```

I don't, how do I get Python to return the correct result rather than `$1`? Is `re.sub` even the right function to do this?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

Simply use [`\1`](http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax) instead of `$1`:

```
In [1]: import re

In [2]: method = 'images/:id/huge'

In [3]: re.sub(r'(:[a-z]+)', r'<span>\1</span>', method)
Out[3]: 'images/<span>:id</span>/huge'
```

Also note the use of [raw strings](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#string-and-bytes-literals) (`r'...'`) for regular expressions. It is not mandatory but removes the need to escape backslashes, arguably making the code slightly more readable.

Comment: For those looking for this example and wondering why it fails on your tests, make sure to add the r (character 'r') before the group string

Comment: The `r` specifier was the issue this answer helped me with as well.

Comment: `\g<0>` works when there is no matching group, i.e. for a non-grouping regex like `':[a-z]+'`. Straight from https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub

Comment: is there a way to modify what's in \1 before the substitution?

Answer (score 19):

A backreference to the whole match value is `\g<0>`, see [`re.sub` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub):

> The backreference `\g<0>` substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/TFMUlz):

```py
import re
method = 'images/:id/huge'
print(re.sub(r':[a-z]+', r'<span>\g<0></span>', method))
# => images/<span>:id</span>/huge
```

If you need to perform a case insensitive search, add `flag=re.I`:

```py
re.sub(r':[a-z]+', r'<span>\g<0></span>', method, flags=re.I)
```

Comment: `\g<1>` etc are also valid, providing a way to replace with `\11` (\1 and the number 1) as opposed to capture group 11.

Comment: @Orwellophile Yes, this syntax allows to use all the backreferences, not just to Group 0.

Answer (score 18):

Use `\1` instead of `$1`.

> \number Matches the contents of the group of the same number.

http://docs.python.org/library/re.html#regular-expression-syntax

Answer (score 6):

For the replacement portion, Python uses `\1` the way sed and vi do, **not** `$1` the way Perl, Java, and Javascript (amongst others) do.  Furthermore, because `\1` interpolates in regular strings as the character U+0001, you need to use a raw string or \escape it.

```
Python 3.2 (r32:88445, Jul 27 2011, 13:41:33) 
[GCC 4.0.1 (Apple Inc. build 5465)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> method = 'images/:id/huge'
>>> import re
>>> re.sub(':([a-z]+)', r'<span>\1</span>', method)
'images/<span>id</span>/huge'
>>>
```