# Replace captured word with captured word and quotations using regex

Tags: python, regex

I have a string : `'testing:  '` and want to replace it with `' "testing:" '`. 
In other words, add quotations around the word inside the string

I've tried using

```
re.sub('[a-zA-Z]+:', '"${name}"',word)
```

but this just replaces it with `{name}`

Comment: You want `re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]+:', r'"\g<0>"',word)`. No need to capture anything

Comment: try: `re.sub('([a-zA-Z]+:)', r'"\1"',word)`

Comment: You need `re.sub('[a-zA-Z]+:', r'"\g<0>"', word)` See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7191209/python-re-sub-replace-with-matched-content

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use [`\g<0>` backreference](https://docs.python.org/3/library/re.html#re.sub) to refer to the whole match:

> The backreference `\g<0>` substitutes in the entire substring matched by the RE.

Code:

```
word = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]+:', r'"\g<0>"', word)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/9xPBzK)

```
import re
word = 'testing:  '
word = re.sub(r'[a-zA-Z]+:', r'"\g<0>"',word)
print(word) # => "testing:"
```

Answer (score 2):

Your original expression is just fine, we'd just add a capturing group around it,

```
([A-Za-z]+:)
```

#### [Demo](https://regex101.com/r/tweNqV/1/)

#### Test

```
# coding=utf8
# the above tag defines encoding for this document and is for Python 2.x compatibility

import re

regex = r"([A-Za-z]+:)"

test_str = "testing:"

subst = "\"\\1\""

# You can manually specify the number of replacements by changing the 4th argument
result = re.sub(regex, subst, test_str, 0, re.MULTILINE)

if result:
    print (result)

# Note: for Python 2.7 compatibility, use ur"" to prefix the regex and u"" to prefix the test string and substitution.
```

#### Output

```
"testing:"
```

#### Examples of re.sub

```
result = re.sub(pattern, repl, string, count=0, flags=0);
```

---

```
result = re.sub('abc',  '',    input)           # Delete pattern abc
result = re.sub('abc',  'def', input)           # Replace pattern abc -> def
result = re.sub(r'\s+', ' ',   input)           # Eliminate duplicate whitespaces
result = re.sub('abc(def)ghi', r'\1', input)    # Replace a string with a part of itself
```

#### [Reference](https://docs.python.org/2/library/re.html)

#### RegEx Circuit

[jex.im](https://jex.im/regulex/#!flags=&re=%5E(a%7Cb)*%3F%24) visualizes regular expressions:

[image]

Comment: It captures the expression,  but I'm having difficulty with the replacement regex string

Comment: Thank you for this! can you explain what you are doing with substr

Comment: @user3688791 Do not wrap the whole pattern with a capturing group, that adds a tiny but overhead to the regex engine. Use the dedicated backreference to the whole match.